# Set entity reference target_id in migration yml

Tags: 8, entities, migrations

I migrate Drupal 6 to Drupal 8. In Drupal 8 I have content type that has field with type `Entity reference` that reference specific taxonomy dictionary. I can't find out how to set `Entity reference` field `target_id` in `yml` migration file. I have tried:

```
field_my_field:
  plugin: iterator
  source: field_my_field
  process:
    target_id:
      plugin: default_value
      default_value: 19
```

I would expect that code above set Entity reference (`field_my_field`) to reference term with id `19` (that already exists). There is no error (or message) and `default_value` plugin is called correctly a returns `19`. But in migrated content is not reference set.

I tried to set reference manually and then dump it and result was:

```
[field_my_field] => Array
  (
    [x-default] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
          (
            [target_id] => 19
          )
      )
  )
```

I have tried lot of other ways how to set entity reference `target_id` but nothing actually work. Do anybody know how to set entity reference `target_id` in migration yml file?

Comment: Hi do you any update on this? I'm facing the same situation, my code is very similar, everything seems to run well, but the association is not saved.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I'm guessing you need to add the array for the item list. I was successful with:

`field_something/0/target_id: YOUR_VALUE_HERE`

I haven't found documentation on the slash in the field id, but it is an array notation. The above is equivalent to something like:

`$destination_values['field_something'][0]['target_id'] = YOUR_VALUE_HERE`

Answer (score 1):

Is 19 the tid of an already-existing Drupal 8 term in the vocabulary that field_my_field is configured to reference? If so, I don't really see where the example using default_value would be going wrong...